# Recommended way to organise shared modules browserify/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a rather large javascript-project, with various shared modules.
Thus I often end up with requires that looks like this

```
var CommonModule = require('../../../common/shared_module.js')
```

It would make sense to split the functionality residing in common/ into it's own package. However moving common/ to node_modules seems a bit obscure. Is there a recommended way to organise shared content?

To me, it would seem logical to have multiple projects

```
main_project/
shared_resources/
some_other_shared/
```

And somehow link these projects in main. But I haven't been able to find a smooth solution.

Any better ideas?=)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with my own files, but if you put a module into node_modules at the project root, the entire subtree will be able to access it.  npm doesn't install an inner dependency if it's already present at the root.

Answer (score 0):

I save the __rootdir in the global variable in the entry of my app.

```
global.__rootdir = __dirname;
```

so when I want to require my common module in the deep nested module, I use

```
require(path.join(__rootdir, 'lib/somelib');
```

another way is to use symbal link to link your common module into node_modules, so that you can require your module eaisly

```
require('commmon/somelib');
```

if you use the second way, remember to exclude your moudle in the .gitignore file. basically, you dont want to save all your node_modules in the source control.

here is a nice post relate to this question. must have a look at this  https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520